# How to implement a string data container and use it to add two strings with Kotlin and Antlr

Tags: kotlin, parsing, compiler-construction, antlr

I'm trying to make my own language parser using Kotlin and Antlr.  I'm trying to implement a data container for the string data and have the code execute.

Code to be executed:

```
val program = """
x = "Hello";
y = "World";

// Expect "Hello World"
print(x ++ y);
"""
```

So far, my Kotlin backend is:

```
package backend
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*
import mygrammar.*

abstract class Data

data class StringData(val value: String) : Data()
data class IntData(val value: Int): Data()

class Context: HashMap<String, Data>()

abstract class Expr {
    abstract fun eval(scope: Context): Data
}


class Compiler: PLBaseVisitor<Expr>() {
}
```

My Antlr grammar is:

```
grammar PL;

@header {
package mygrammar;
}

program     : statement* EOF
        ;

statement   : assignment ';'    # assignmentStatement
        | expr ';'      # exprStatement
        ;

assignment  : 'let' ID '=' expr
        ;

expr        : x=expr '+' y=expr # addExpr
        | x=expr '-' y=expr # subExpr
        | x=expr '*' y=expr # mulExpr
        | x=expr '/' y=expr # divExpr
        | '(' expr ')'      # parenExpr
        | value         # valueExpr
        ;

value       : NUMERIC       # numericValue
        | STRING        # stringValue
        | ID            # idValue
        ;


NUMERIC     : ('0' .. '9')+ ('.' ('0' .. '9')*)?
        ;

STRING      : '"' ( '\\"' | ~'"' )* '"'
        ;

ID      : ('a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z' | '_') ('a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z' | '0' .. '9' | '_')*
        ;

COMMENT     : '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip
        ;

WHITESPACE  : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ -> skip
        ;
```

I've been trying to search for the next steps, but whatever I search always seems to give me results for how to compile Kotlin code, not how to compile your own code using Kotlin.

Comment: One thing you'll want to do is add the `++` operator to your grammar (assuming you want to spell the string concatenation operator that way). Beyond that, try to keep run-time and compilation separate. In the most basic compiler architecture, program text is turned into an AST (much of which is done by Antlr), and then the AST is turned into a datastructure which represents the execution sequence embodied in the program text. That might be a vector of actual machine instructions, or a vector of virtual machine intructions, or even simply the AST itself...

Comment: That thing -- the object file -- must then be executed in some kind of run-time environment. That's where the string container will live. I think you're still several tasks away from that.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few steps between having an ANTLR grammar and executing your code.

The very next step is to use ANTLR to generate source code for a parser to recognize source code matching your grammar.  Since Kotlin is pretty good with Java Interop, you could just generate and compile the Java target for your grammar.  (If you want to stick with Kotlin, I see there is support for that here [ANTLR Kotlin](https://github.com/Strumenta/antlr-kotlin/). (I've not used it myself, but do know the Strumenta Community, so I would expect it to be good. (It looks like there's a good intro from them [here](https://tomassetti.me/building-and-testing-a-parser-with-antlr-and-kotlin/))

Once you have compiled your generated parser, you should be able to find sample code for calling the parser on your source (`program` in your example).  This will give you a ParseTree.  ANTLR provides convenience classes in the form of Listeners and/or Visitors that make it easy to process the resulting parse tree.  At this point, ANTLR has provided it's value for you.  ANTLR is a tool for generating source code for a parser to recognize your input.  The ParseTree is the result of that parsing.  From there, it is up to you to decide how to handle interpreting that parse tree and executing the logic.

If your language does not get too much more complicated, and is not particularly performance sensitive, you might get by with logic to visit the tree performing the logic represented there (keep a dictionary of values, interpreting and performing the operations in the ParseTree, etc.)

Your question suggests that you may expect ANTLR to be able to compile and execute your logic.  That's just simply not the case.  What I've outlined would be the next steps in a way forward, and there are many ways that you may choose to get to execution of the logic.

If you need an intro to ANTLR this one is pretty good: [ANTLR Mega Tutorial](https://tomassetti.me/antlr-mega-tutorial/)

And this page links to many more [Strumenta ANTLR articles](https://tomassetti.me/category/language-engineering/antlr/)